# sscanf and strtok not returning a "complete" answer

Tags: c, strtok, scanf

I have a string of characters which is separated in to two groups by " | "; space, vertical bar/pipe, space. There will only ever be four characters in the string, "ACGT". My problem is that if I use sscanf or strtok I can read in the first string group fine, but the second string group only ever contains the first character of the group.

The relevant snips are thus:

```
typedef struct {
  char strings[1][399]; // 2D array of the strings
  int length[1]; // Line Length 1 and 2
} DoubleLOT;

char line[1024]; // Each string can only be a max of 400 chars anyway
DoubleLOT inStrings; // structs to hold string sequences

// Init variables
for (a=0;a<=1;a++){
  strcpy(inStrings.strings[a], "");
  inStrings.length[a]=0;
}

strcpy(line, "GAAT | GAAT");
```

Using sscanf();

```
sscanf(line, "%[ACGT] | %[ACGT]", inStrings.strings[0], inStrings.strings[1]);
inStrings.length[0]=strlen(inStrings.strings[0]);
inStrings.length[1]=strlen(inStrings.strings[1]);
printf(">%s< %i\n", inStrings.strings[0], inStrings.length[0]);
printf(">%s< %i\n", inStrings.strings[1], inStrings.length[1]);
```

returns:

```
>GAAT< 4
>G< 2
```

Using strtok() such as:

```
strcpy(inStrings.strings[0], strtok(line, " |"));
strcpy(inStrings.strings[1], strtok(NULL, " |"));
inStrings.length[0]=strlen(inStrings.strings[0]);
inStrings.length[1]=strlen(inStrings.strings[1]);
printf(">%s< %i\n", inStrings.strings[0], inStrings.length[0]);
printf(">%s< %i\n", inStrings.strings[1], inStrings.length[1]);
```

returns again:

```
>GAAT< 4
>G< 2
```

In this example, I want to be seeing:

```
>GAAT< 4
>GAAT< 4
```

I've tried removing the | character from "line" and still the same problem. I originally had %s instead of %[ACGT], same problem. The fact that the two strings are the same here doesn't help me any, but I figure once I have the problem fixed, that should be irrelevant. Besides, I've tried with multiple different strings as well.

I'm assuming it's something I'm doing with either memory or how the functions are handling memory that's throwing me. I'm also assuming that the`>G< 2` is referring to a `\0` at the end - which I also can't figure how it's being injected into the string. An inspection of "line" after the sscanf() reveals that it is indeed still in-tact and identical to "line" before the function call -- though I can't do the same with strtok() meaningfully.

*Note:* I don't care if I chew up "line" using strtok(); once I break it up into its two parts I'm done with it.

Comment: With `char strings[1][399];`, `for (a=0;a<=1;a++){` is out of bound access.

Comment: `char foo[1][399]` - 1 means the size of that dimension is *exactly* 1, this is no "Visual Basic math".

Comment: *doh* Yes, I did remember that arrays are 0 referenced, but forgot that you assign them as the total size starting at 1. TYVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is **undefined behaviour**. You declared your struct having a member called `strings` that is array of 1 by 399 chars; and another one `length` that is array of **one** integer, but are writing outside their bounds.

Your `typedef` should be

```
typedef struct {
    char strings[2][399];
    int length[2];
} DoubleLOT;
```

Or, if the maximum length of a string is **400** characters as you state in comments, that 399 should be replaced with **401** - 400 characters and terminating `'\0'`.

---

But beyond that, I can tell what is happening on your platform and why exactly you are seeing that output.

The following struct

```
typedef struct {
    char strings[1][399]; // 2D array of the strings
    int length[1]; // Line Length 1 and 2
} DoubleLOT;
```

would, on a normal LP64 architecture, have an 1x399 array of char, followed by 1 padding byte, followed by 4-aligned array of one 32-bit integer.

Now when you copy into `inString.strings[0]`, everything is fine for as long as the string fits into those 399 characters. But writing to `inString.strings[1]` is undefined behaviour because that memory is not allocated. However in *this* case everything is seemingly fine, because the string `"GAAT"` is written so that the `'G'` goes to the padding byte, and the `"AAT"` and terminating `'\0'` will get written over the `inString.length[0]`.

After that you write the length of `inString.strings[0]`; 4 in little endian, into `inString.length[0]`. The bytes `0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00` are written over bytes `'A', 'A', 'T' and '\0'`;

now `inString.strings[1]` looks like it has only 1 character; the second one, ASCII 4, is a non-printable control character. But it is there, as evidenced by fact that the `strlen(inString.strings[1])` is 2, not 1.

Finally, the `strlen(inString.strings[1])` is written over something else on stack/global variables, following `DoubleLOT inStrings;`.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment - that worked perfectly. I should have seen that a mile away. Bedankt.